# How to find syntax error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I evaluate a function in one cell, Mathematica says

```
ToExpression::notstrbox: {At Line = 6, the input was:,$Failed,InString[6]} 
is not a string or a box. ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes 
as Mathematica input. >>
```

And the cell right edge turns red.

How do I find the error location?

Comment: I found the syntax error: I have raised an x to the second power, but instead of writing x^2 I used the 2D math notation and typed x CTRL^2.  It seems this sometimes causes a problem by introducing some hidden character. When I changed it back to x^2 the error went away. This does not happen all the time and it seems to be random and rare. To be safe, I will stop using 2D math notation in code from now on even though it did make the code look better but it seems buggy to me.

Comment: I haven't seen that kind of errors since version 2 or 3. As I recall it was mainly editing matched quotes that could wreak havok. I use 2D notation all the time. Perhaps your installation is corrupt or so?

Comment: My installation is just fine. As I said, this error is rare. I use 2D math all the time also and saw this problem once now. because you did not see the error for sometime yourself does not mean much, and it does not mean the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In reality, the kernel always sends the position of first syntax error in the input string to the FrontEnd (if this input string contains an error). It can be demonstrated with the following MathLink code:

```
In[32]:= link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink"];
LinkRead[link];
LinkWrite[link, EnterTextPacket["2+"]]
LinkRead[link]
LinkRead[link]
LinkRead[link]

Out[35]= MessagePacket[Syntax, "sntxi"]    
Out[36]= TextPacket["Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.
 "]    
Out[37]= SyntaxPacket[5]
```

The integer in `SyntaxPacket` "indicates the position at which a syntax error was detected in the input line" according to the documentation. What is confusing at first is that this position in the case of the input line "`2+`" is obviously beyond the end of the input line. But it seems that in reality this position is counted for the `InputForm` of the input line which in this case is: "`2+\n\n`".

We can check how it works with `$SyntaxHandler` defined as follows:

```
In[41]:= link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink"];
LinkRead[link]
LinkWrite[link, 
 EnterTextPacket[
  "$SyntaxHandler=
      Function[{str,pos},
               Print["Input string: ",ToString[str,InputForm]];
               Print["Position of syntax error: ",pos];
               $Failed
      ];
  "]]
LinkRead[link]
LinkWrite[link, EnterTextPacket["2+"]]
While[Head[packet = LinkRead[link]] =!= InputNamePacket, 
 Print[packet]]; Print[packet]

Out[42]= InputNamePacket["In[1]:= "]    
Out[44]= InputNamePacket["In[2]:= "]    
During evaluation of In[41]:= MessagePacket[Syntax,sntxi]    
During evaluation of In[41]:= TextPacket[Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.
]    
During evaluation of In[41]:= TextPacket[Input string: "2+\n\n"
]    
During evaluation of In[41]:= TextPacket[Position of syntax error: 6
]    
During evaluation of In[41]:= SyntaxPacket[5]    
During evaluation of In[41]:= InputNamePacket[In[2]:= ]
```

One can see an inconsistency between the positions of the same syntax error reported by `SyntaxPacket` and by `$SyntaxHandler`. But it seems possible to understand how they count the position: both use `InputForm` of the input line and the position *before* the input line has number 0 for `$SyntaxHandler` and number 1 in the case of `SyntaxPacket`. In this way we can define `$SyntaxHandler` for getting exact visual representation of the position of the syntax error inside of the input string (**the input `Cell` must have "RawInputForm" style**) as follows:

```
$SyntaxHandler = 
  Function[{str, pos}, 
   Print["Input string: ", ToString[str, InputForm], "\n", 
    "Position of syntax error: ", pos, "\n", 
    StringInsert[ToString[str, InputForm], 
     ToString[Style["\[DownArrowBar]", Red, Background -> Yellow], 
      StandardForm], pos + 2]]; $Failed];
```

I will stress again that input cell MUST have the "RawInputForm" style! Such cell may be created by creating ordinary empty input cell and then converting it to the "RawInputForm" cell by the appropriate command in the `Cell -> Convert To` menu.

Lets see how it works:

[image: screenshot]

The reason why we must use "RawInputForm" cell is probably that `$SyntaxHandler` is applied ony when the input is sent to the kernel in the form of a `String`, not in the form of `Boxes` as it happens with default `StandardForm` input cells.

Answer (score 6):

Are you calling `ToExpression` yourself on a string? The function [`SyntaxLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SyntaxLength.html) will give you the character offset of the first syntax error when applied to a string, for example:

```
In[26]:= SyntaxLength["2+"]
Out[26]= 4

In[27]:= SyntaxLength["x[1]+x[2]]"]
Out[27]= 9
```

Note that as indicated in the docs, when `SyntaxLength` returns a position beyond the end of the input string, that means the expression is syntactically correct so far, but incomplete. Otherwise, `SyntaxLength` effectively returns the position of the first syntax error.

If you're not explicitly invoking `ToExpression` on something, it will probably help to see the cell in question.

Comment: I am not calling ToExpression. I do not know what that is for actually. I am asking if there is a tool or method to find the actual locations of syntax errors in a notebook. Clearly there must be an automated way to tell Mathematica to report such information other just generating a message saying that a syntax error did occur somewhere.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: If you're not directly using `ToExpression`, then this could be a bug in something else that you are using.  Interestingly, when I try `ToExpression[{"aaaa",$Failed,InString[6]}]`, I don't get any errors at all.  I'll second the suggestion to post the portion of your notebook that is causing the error.

Comment: Like Sjoerd said in another answer, many syntax errors should be flagged inline with colored syntax highlighting. See `Preferences > Appearance > Syntax Coloring > Errors and Warnings` for examples and tweaks.  If nothing obvious is jumping out in your cell, it's possibly an internal bug as Brett noted, and we'd be curious to see it.

Answer (score 4):

Syntax errors such as unbalanced function brackets, are usually indicated by means of character coloring, an unmatched bracket turning pink or so. In this case, there has been an input type error. Apparently, you called (or a function you used did) ToExpression using the result of another function that failed. First step would be finding this ToExpression and finding out what function providing its input returns $Failed.

Mathematica has a bare-bones debugger, which you can find in the Evaluation menu. A better debugger may be found in Matimatica Workbench which is free if you have a Premier Service license.

If your code is not too large I'd suggest posting it as part of your question. We're not a code review site, though.